# 'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: react-native, gradlew

So i am trying to start a react native android project in windows 10 based on the [Getting Start React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). 
I am stuck at the last step->react-native run-android

[image: Screenshot of command prompt]

ps: Im using genymotion for my  android emulator marshmallow 6.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it,

Add the file location to environment variable PATH

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper

Comment: I do not have `templates/` directory in my `tools/` directory. I have tried the other solution (of adding `gradle` installation path) but have no success. I am missing `gradlew.bat`

Comment: However the `gradle -v` command works well, as I have added Gradle installation path to environment variable. I'm using Win 10.

Answer (score 2):

Another version of the @Kai Jie findings, that works for me.

Compiling previous answers I did the following to get Android SDK and gradle working (You need gradle working anyway to compile your Android project):

1. Prerequisites. You have gradle installed in the folders like I found on my computer. Please, check it:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-X.X\
   ```
2. Set a new system variable (Control Panel\System and Security\System Advance system ->settings->environment variables-system variables). Do not forget to change a gradle version.

   ```
   GRADLE_HOME   C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-X.X\
   ```
3. Add the following path to system paths (Control Panel\System and Security\System Advance system ->settings->environment variables-system variables):

   ```
   %GRADLE_HOME%\bin
   ```
4. You might want to REBOOT your computer, to make sure, that the system sees the variables.
5. Check if gradle works properly with the terminal commands

   ```
   $ gradle -v
   ```

Comment: I do not have `templates/` directory in my `tools/` directory. I have tried the other solution (of adding `gradle` installation path) but have no success. I am missing `gradlew.bat`. The `gradle -v` command works though.

Answer (score 1):

If the environment variables are set. I found that you need to actually start gradle. Then you can use the gradlew command.

If you are learning from Spring.io. Their site says to just run

```
./gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
```

That will fail unless you first run

```
gradle
```

Intellij had me in the correct directory so I just deleted

```
./
```

and run

```
gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
```

The app started right up.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)
```

Answer (score 1):

if your gradlew.bat file is being generated but delete itself after a few second than it's a problem of your android studio .
steps to follow :
1 . open your android studio and click on configure.
2. Go to setting there.
3.Click on Build,Execution,Deployment => Build Tools => Gradle.
4. check Gradle user home if it's pointing to .gradle file location or not .If it's not than give the correct path of .gradle file like this in my case C:/Users/Your_PC_Name/.gradle .
5. And than create new reactproject.

Comment: Thank you , you saved me

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to do something like:

./gradlew assembleDebug

Answer (score 0):

Add code below to the bottom of build.gradle file

```
task createWrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.9'
};
```

then run `gradle createWrapper` in terminal

This will generate gradlew.bat file and corrospondinf gradlew files

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I had a & sign in the name of the folder that I had put in the flutter project. removing it solved the problem for me.